# How to use Json File to serve as a data source for webapi

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I want to retrieve data from Json file with webapi using Json file as data source.

In the controller, I have added following code:

```
Public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data\Bim.Json"));

      return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
    };
}
```

and in model,

```
public class bimModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string material { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public string contentType { get; set; }
}
```

Actually, I want to use a json file which is located in app_data folder, how to read data from JSON file? I am very new to the webApi, so it will be of great help if the experts can post the entire working code or as many details as possible, please.

Comment: your question is not clear, what is your issue? why does your Action not work? why do you have a model where is it used?

Answer (score 2):

If I am correct, I believe you want to deserialize the json text file to model classes, then serialize them back to json for the client.

To do this, you can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/ to help you out. Follow the instructions to get the package installed.

Once you do that, you can write a function such as

```
public bimModel Get()
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data\Bim.Json"));
    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bimModel>(json);

    return model;
}
```

If your json file is an array of `bimModels`, then you can change the return type and type parameter of `DeserializeObject` to `List<bimModel>`.

To ensure your server is returning json to the client, make sure your `WebApiConfig` class is using the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Formatters.Clear();
    config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
}
```

And of course, be sure to include `using Newtonsoft.Json;` and `using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;`

Comment: Thank you @Kevin Le

Comment: If this works, would you mind upvoting/marking as answered? Thanks!